# How to show entire world map once in full width and automatic height in Syncfusion Blazor?

Tags: c#, maps, openstreetmap, blazor, syncfusion

I'm trying to create a app to show certain items on a map. This world within this map only needs to be shown once on the full width of screen so height is determined automatic.

What i got now:

[image]

As you can see here the map is displayed full width but the world is displayed 3 times in this. I want it only to be shown once and the height will increase automatically to scale.. How can i achieve this?

Code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
            <SfCard ID="">
                <CardHeader Title="locations" />
                <CardContent>
                    <SfMaps>
                        @* To zoom and pan *@
                        <MapsZoomSettings Enable="true"
                                          Toolbars='new string[]{"Zoom", "ZoomIn", "ZoomOut", "Pan", "Reset" }'>
                        </MapsZoomSettings>
                        <MapsLayers>
                            <MapsLayer LayerType="ShapeLayerType.OSM" >
                            </MapsLayer>
                        </MapsLayers>
                    </SfMaps>
                </CardContent>
            </SfCard>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed the provided image and came to know that you are trying to render the maps based on the card component size. We have handled the OSM map with some specific height and width. So the maps gets repeated in the extra space in the control and the maps features like markers and navigation lines will be added in the center map. However, we can zoom the maps in the center using ZoomFactor property. We have created a sample to demonstrate the same and it can be downloaded from the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/BlazorApp1_(6)1787155629

In the above sample, we have rendered the OSM map with “ZoomFactor” property in “MapsZoomSettings” in maps.

Please let us know that the above sample meets your requirement. If not, please provide us more details about your requirement. It will be helpful for us to analyze further and assist you better.

Regards,
Swetha Babu

Comment: Please remember, you can also use **Bold** text in your answer

Comment: Hi, so it is not possible to increase the height of the card so the entire world map can be shown once?